# Any IDE's in Ubuntu for Windows Development with C Sharp?

Tags: windows, programming, ide, c#

I'm wondering if you folks could steer me toward some Window's Dev IDE tools for ASP.Net and or C Sharp? 
Is there a good site for finding IDE's for Ubuntu? I've not totally installed yet, just looked at it and have been impressed running of DVD in my DVD Drive.

Answer (score 6):

[MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) is an opensource IDE for doing cross platform development c#. It also works with ASP.net

It is available from the ubuntu software centre:

[image: Install via the software center]

Alternatively if your the command line loving type:

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use mono IDE for windows development. It will let you program .net development too

From this link you can download and install it

http://monodevelop.com/Download

Comment: I wouldn't try and get it from that download link, when it is included in the ubuntu software center already.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing WINE program.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Then try installing the .exe file of visual studio as you do it in windows...

I hope it works.

Comment: Trying to use Visual Studio through wine is not a good idea. Trust me. Better to use Mono Develop which is a native linux application.